# How does the "Subdividing Tax Lots" scheme work?

Tags: united-states, taxes, real-estate, new-york, property-taxes

In an [article that broke](https://www.insider.com/manhattan-developer-new-york-200-amsterdam-2020-2) today, a Manhattan developer was charged with "subdividing tax lots" in order to get around zoning laws limiting the height of a skyscraper.

What does it mean to subdivide a tax lot and how could one game this in order to get around zoning laws?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your linked article doesn't use that term, I think this is talking about 'gerrymandered' zoning lots. This article shows one example lot:
[Crain’s Reveals Gerrymandered Zoning Lot](https://www.landmarkwest.org/crains-reveals-gerrymandered-zoning-lot/) (Or do an image search for "200 Amsterdam Ave".)

Here, the legal lot includes a bunch of space that is unrelated to the building under construction, apparently in order to provide enough open space to build the size of tower desired.